How to write an azure devops yaml with special characters
I am trying to write a pipeline task that produces a file (run.sh) that will be run by my docker container to replace some javascript with environment variables in the container.
Unfortunately the pipeline is trying to interpret the ${var1} and ${var2} which is what I want to happen when the script is actually executed.
The script itself would work just fine if I can get it into the docker container.
- script: |
    tee -a run.sh <<EOF
    #!/bin/sh

    ###replace configuration with environment variables
    /bin/sed -i 's@https://development-website.mywebsite.cloud@'"${var1}@g" /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/index*.js
    /bin/sed -i 's@https://development-login.mywebsite.cloud@'"${var2}@g" /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/index*.js

    EOF
  displayName: "make run.sh"


Downvoters please leave a comment. Just trying to figure out how to escape a complicated string in yaml, this question seems reasonable to me

You can add backslash \ before ${var}, like \${var1} in the task.
Sample below:
pool:
  vmImage: Ubuntu-latest     ## use linux anget

steps:
- script: |
    tee -a run.sh <<EOF
    #!/bin/sh

    ###replace configuration with environment variables
    /bin/sed -i 's@https://development-website.mywebsite.cloud@'"\${var1}@g" /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/index*.js
    /bin/sed -i 's@https://development-login.mywebsite.cloud@'"\${var2}@g" /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/index*.js

    EOF
  displayName: "make run.sh"


The output:

